# HTML elements in response using htmx's websockets extension are getting hyphens added, tags commented out

Tags: websocket, htmx

I am using the htmx [websockets extension](https://htmx.org/extensions/web-sockets/).

I have a list of players on my page.

I want to send a message from my backend over the WebSocket to add a player to the list.

I send the message `<li id="player-list" hx-swap-oob="beforeend" type="1">player 2</ li>`.

What gets added to the HTML is:

```
"player 2"
<!-- li-->
```

It's as if the HTML `li` element is getting sanitized, with `<li>...</li>` changed to `"..."<!-- li-->`.

My HTML page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/ext/ws.js"></script>
    <title>Hat Game: Your Room Code</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
  <h1>Your room code</h1>
  <p>
    Give this code to everyone in your group:
    <span id="room-code">RSTWAG</span>.
  </p>
  <p>
    As everyone enters the room code, you will see their names populate below.
    When your entire group is there, tap <b><em>Everybody's in</em></b
    >.
  </p>
  <div id="players-in-the-room">
    <h2>Players in the room</h2>
    <ol id="player-list" hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws-roster/?roomcode=RSTWAG">
      <li type="1">fur</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="ws-messages"></div>
</body>

  </body>
</html>
```

For testing purposes, I am sending the message over the WebSocket with:

```
aws --profile hat-game-prod apigatewaymanagementapi post-to-connection \
  --data $(echo -n '<li id="player-list" hx-swap-oob="beforeend" type="1">player 2</ li>' | base64) \
  --connection-id ${CONNECTION_ID} \
  --endpoint-url https://qu3vq8riw2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ws-roster
```

The text `player 2` gets added in the right place, but not within HTML tags:

[image]

It seems the message is received as intended, based on the Messages I can see in dev tools:

[image]

I would like for my `<ol>` element to look like:

```html
    <ol id="player-list" hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws-roster/?roomcode=RSTWAG">
      <li type="1">fur</li>
      <li type="1">player 2</li>
    </ol>
```

instead of

```html
    <ol id="player-list" hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws-roster/?roomcode=RSTWAG">
      <li type="1">fur</li>
      "player 2"
      <!-- li-->
    </ol>
```

after I send an `li` element over the WebSocket.

I've tried in Chrome and Firefox with the same result.

The repo is at https://github.com/douglasnaphas/hatgame, though I believe the relevant code is included above.

Comment: I don't know anything about htmx, but two observations that may help you.  1: Something is stripping your HTML tags, and that's probably intentional.  Check your htmx library to see if it has this feature and if it can be removed.  2: Sending HTML over WebSocket to be then embedded into the page is a nightmare.  You'd have to manage your templates on both sides of this.  Can you just send the data instead?  Many folks just encode data as JSON and then insert it into the page with a simple template on the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Using htmx (https://htmx.org) involves sending HTML over WebSockets. It's intentionally different from most normal JavaScript libraries in that sense. There are a lot of concise explanations at https://htmx.org/talk/#podcasts of why this is, if you're interested. I unfortunately have not found anyone else posting anything about this kind of tag-stripping with htmx.

Comment: Do you have a URL to your page running by chance?  I'd like to poke at it in the debugger.

Comment: @Brad It's https://hat-game.com/room-code/RSTWAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User rtrjl on the [htmx Discord](https://htmx.org/discord) explained that the correct way to do what I'm trying to do is to have the top-level element in my WebSocket message be an `ol` element, not an `li` element.

The following worked, as suggested on my [cross-posted question](https://discord.com/channels/725789699527933952/1177439988284137602) on Discord:

```
aws --profile hat-game-prod apigatewaymanagementapi post-to-connection \
  --data $(echo -n '<ol id="player-list" hx-swap-oob="beforeend"> <li> type="1">player 2 </li> </ol>' | base64) \
  --connection-id ${CONNECTION_ID} \
  --endpoint-url https://qu3vq8riw2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ws-roster
```